# Reading Json object with inside array

Tags: php, json

This is my JSON result:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "http://wabi-west-europe-redirect.analysis.windows.net/v1.0/collections/washington/workspaces/37380bc1-dd47-4c95-8dbd-5efecafc8b26/$metadata#reports",
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "6ea77895-f92a-4ca6-90f7-cdade3683cd6",
      "modelId": 0,
      "name": "america",
      "webUrl": "https://app.powerbi.com/reports/6ea77895-f92a-4ca6-90f7-cdade3683cd6",
      "embedUrl": "https://embedded.powerbi.com/appTokenReportEmbed?reportId=6ea77895-f92a-4ca6-90f7-cdade3683cd6",
      "isOwnedByMe": true,
      "isOriginalPbixReport": false,
      "datasetId": "3f1f480c-4a8c-4756-87eb-fc29f5d76de3"
    },
    {
      "id": "ce558be6-aaf9-4bee-b344-6db7754e572b",
      "modelId": 0,
      "name": "dency",
      "webUrl": "https://app.powerbi.com/reports/ce558be6-aaf9-4bee-b344-6db7754e572b",
      "embedUrl": "https://embedded.powerbi.com/appTokenReportEmbed?reportId=ce558be6-aaf9-4bee-b344-6db7754e572b",
      "isOwnedByMe": true,
      "isOriginalPbixReport": false,
      "datasetId": "5264cf84-214a-4c33-8f8e-f421d8ce1846"
    }
  ]
}
```

In PHP im getting into

```
$response = json_decode($aboveresult);
```

But My problem is the value is in array.I want to get both the array value like id,modelId,Name,...
Please help me.
I tried $response['value'].But its showing error like **Cannot use object of type stdClass as array**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change:

```
$response = json_decode($aboveresult,true);
```

When you mentioned the second parameter as `true` you will get the `ASSOCIATIVE` array

Comment: yes correct.I have tried this.But that time some other error came so that i confused.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`json_decode()` accepts a second parameter, which is by default `false`. If you pass `true`, the function will return you an associative `array` instead of an instance of `stdClass` and you can work with it the way you tried before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo "<pre>";
$json_data = json_decode($json);  //$json = your json string 


print_r($json_data->value);

foreach($json_data->value as $value) {
    echo 'ID: '.$value->id .'<br>';
    echo 'modelId: '.$value->modelId .'<br>';
    echo 'name: '.$value->name .'<br>';
}
```